# Run IPython Notebook server in background in Ubuntu using "service"-style commands

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, daemon, background-process, jupyter-notebook

I have set up IPython Notebook on my machine (within a virtualenv).  And I have set up a profile (called `myserver`) which is appropriate for my needs.  For now, I kick off that server by executing:

```
cd path/to/folder/containing/virtualenv
source virtualenvfolder/bin/activate
ipython notebook --profile=myserver
```

I'd like to run this same process in the background, and I'd like to manage it the way I manage other things in my Ubuntu install...with commands like `sudo service ngninx start` or `sudo service uwsgi restart` or `sudo service lightdm stop`.  I.e.  I'd like to be able to type `sudo service myipythonserver start|stop|restart` and have it behave in the expected way.

Four questions.

1. What is the name of the framework that's being used when I call `sudo service something action`.  Is that `Supervisor`?  Something else?
2. Whatever that framework is called, how do I create a new "thing" for it to manage?  What user owns the process that is started in this way, and how do you manage file permissions (etc) for the background process?
3. Once I've created that new "command" (say it now works to type `sudo service myipythonserver start|stop|restart`), how do I set it up so that the process starts automatically on system startup?
4. Is there any way to control the amount of system resources consumed by one of these background processes?  For example, if I want to restrict my IPython server to use no more than 3gb of RAM, is that possible?  No more than 50% of CPU?

Comment: I am not a linux expert , but I think You will probably be better off if you turn your script into an **Upstart job** (ubuntu is movig away from system init service "/etc/init.d/ like). [This](http://bxia.net/blog/2013/08/01/upstart-daemonizing/) looks like a good start. and [This](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) for complete documentation.

Comment: Your first link is broken.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this work using upstart, which is included with Ubuntu.  To create a job with upstart, you create a `.conf` file in `/etc/init`.  The filename without the .conf is the name of the service.  Here's the file I created:

```
exec sudo /usr/local/bin/ipython notebook --notebook-dir=/your/notebook/path   
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
```

The first line includes the path to the ipython binary, and the `--notebook-dir` has the path to where my notebooks are stored.  More detailed configuration could be specified using an  [iPython Profile](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html).  Upstart system files can include [scripts](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html), which could activate your virtualenv.

The second line starts iPython when there's a usable filesystem and network interface.  The service can be started and stopped manually using `sudo start ipython` and `sudo stop ipython`.